# hyperledger fabric chaincode dev mode connection error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I was following this tutorial of building a simple chaincode in dev mode [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.htm). 
I'm stuck [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#terminal-1-start-the-network)
First I cleared everything with `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`. 
When I enter `docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up` it ends with this `Error: Error getting broadcast client: Error connecting to orderer:7050 due to context deadline exceeded
cli          | Usage:
cli          |   peer channel create [flags]
cli          | 
orderer      | 2017-12-05 20:44:53.681 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 0d1 Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
orderer      | 2017-12-05 20:44:53.681 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 0d2 Closing Deliver stream
cli exited with code 1`

What is causing problem? Is it dns problem that it can't find orderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured that out, the problem is in network, so I had in my virtual machine parameters set NAT for network, and nothing worked. I've set it to bridge mode and everything worked fine.